# How to put calculated value from loop into an array using append

Tags: python

I'm solving a problem, and my ultimate goal is to get the precession values in the precession array. These values are the slope of the time vs theta graph. I used a linear fit to get the slope of that graph. I tried to use append to put that slope in the array. This is in a function that is done for differnet a values.

But the array of the precession values is a length of 131, it should only be 24. The code is printing the correct slope (aka the precession values) for each a value when the code is run, but the array is way too long and I don't know where all those values are comign from.

I suspect it's the way i am using append/putting the slope values in the empty array. What can I do to get the values I need in the array?

basically I want to make an array of the differnt slopes of the graph created in my function. When i use append then the slope value (params[0]) the array is a length of 131, when it should be 24, and the values in it are all wrong. How do i make the array of the slopes, the slope for each a value this function runs for?

```
    amin=0
    amax=0.024
    da=0.001
    a_list=np.arange(amin,amax,da)


    for a in a_list:
        mercury(a)    

        ##finding dtheat/dt 
        precession =[]
        #plot theta vs time

        Theta = [theta]

        Time = [time]
        #dtheta/dt dt=period



        #Fitting a straight line! 
        def linefit(x,m,b):
            return m*x+b
        params, param_cov = optimize.curve_fit(linefit,Time,Theta)
        plt.plot(a_list,params[0]*a_list+params[1],'--r',linewidth=2,label='fit')
        plt.plot(Time,Theta)
        plt.xlabel('Time')
        plt.ylabel('Theta')
        plt.title("time vs theta when alpha = {a}".format(a=a))
        plt.show()
        print('slope is %.3f' % (params[0]))  
        precession.append(params[0])

    plt.plot(a_list, precession)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You were resetting the list every loop. I moved it outside the loop.

Edited: Created new array to contain the params[0] to separate values...

```
amin=0
amax=0.024
da=0.001
a_list=np.arange(amin,amax,da)

precession =[] # ADDED HERE
new_array = [] # ADDED HERE
for a in a_list:
    mercury(a)    

    ##finding dtheat/dt 

    #plot theta vs time

    Theta = [theta]

    Time = [time]
    #dtheta/dt dt=period
    for i in theta:
       precession.append(i/0.246)


    #Fitting a straight line! 
    def linefit(x,m,b):
        return m*x+b
    params, param_cov = optimize.curve_fit(linefit,Time,Theta)
    plt.plot(a_list,params[0]*a_list+params[1],'--r',linewidth=2,label='fit')
    plt.plot(Time,Theta)
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Theta')
    plt.title("time vs theta when alpha = {a}".format(a=a))
    plt.show()
    print('slope is %.3f' % (params[0]))  
    new_array.append(params[0]) # ADDED HERE

plt.plot(a_list, precession)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, It's putting the correct slope value now, but only the last slope value, not filling the array with all the values from each time it goes through the function

Comment: I would suggest creating a second list outside the loop where precession is now placed. You are appending to precession at two places in your loop, so it will be off.